# Microservices Contract Testing without provider real API call

Tags: automated-tests, postman, microservices, web-api-testing, pact

In Contract Testing for microservices, first we write mock Provider and create a json contract later this contract will be used to call real provider API call and test the contracts.

Can we mock the real provider call along with json contract ?

Comment: What you mean by json contract ?

Comment: https://link.medium.com/AbwcdCXQXdb

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Pact, then no, it needs to be able to test against a real provider (usually one running locally for dev and on CI).

We're building a more [generalised contract testing](https://github.com/pactflow/roadmap/issues/4) approach at Pactflow that would allow a contract to be generated on the consumer by a Pact test, record/replay or code generation (for example) and for it to be compared against an OAS or other provider contract.

The idea of JSON schema comes up a bit, but the hard challenge there is mapping requests to the correct schema. By the time you do all of that, you have started to essentially rebuild pact but with JSON schema.

And JSON schema has its own set of [challenges](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-mock-validator/issues/84/test-incorrectly-passes-when-mock-expects).

If you want to know more, join the [community slack channel](https://slack.pact.io) and chat with the team.